# Using ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE in PDO

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

How can I use `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` in PDO

My problem is that I get  (SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation?) when I try the following synthaxe, the insert function and update works fine, but when I use both with on duplicate, I get error :

```
    $query = "INSERT INTO my_table (name,tophtml,bothtml,lang,background_mode,redirhtml,bg_color)
              VALUES (:name, :top_html, :bottom_html, :hs_language, :bg_style, :redirect_to, :bg_color )
              ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
              tophtml= :top_html, bothtml= :bottom_html, lang= :hs_language, bg_color= :bg_color, redirhtml= :redirect_to, background_mode= :bg_style WHERE name=:name
             ";
    $request = $databaseStatus->connection->prepare($query);
    $request->bindParam(":name", $name, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $request->bindParam(":top_html", $top_html, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $request->bindParam(":bottom_html", $bottom_html, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $request->bindParam(":bg_color", $bg_color, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $request->bindParam(":redirect_to", $redirect_to, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $request->bindParam(":hs_language", $hs_language, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $request->bindParam(":bg_style", $bg_style, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $request->execute();
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14089055/pdo-prepared-statements-for-insert-and-on-duplicate-key-update-with-named-placeh).
My problem was in the where clause, you don't need to put the table name or SET in the ON DUPLICATE KEY clause, and you don't need a WHERE clause (it always updates the record with the duplicate key).