# mysql PDO where like or query returning only 1 result

Tags: mysql, pdo, sql-like

More than 1 row is returned when i run the following SQL manually through phpMyAdmin:

```
SELECT * 
FROM bread
WHERE (type LIKE '%hite%' OR type LIKE '%grain%' OR type LIKE '%brown%' ) 
AND bread_hide = 0 
LIMIT 20;
```

However, when i run this in PDO, it only returns one result. The SQL is built dynamically for each search word, and looks like this:

```
 SELECT * FROM bread WHERE ( type LIKE :q0 OR type LIKE :q1 OR type LIKE :q2 ) AND bread_hide = 0 LIMIT 20;
```

So if the user enters "hite grain brown", the following params are bound:

```
:q0 = %hite%
:q1 = %grain%
:q2 = %brown%
```

When run manually, i get the following results:

```
white bread
wholegrain
brown bread
```

When run through my PHP PDO query, i only get the last:

```
brown bread
```

if the user enters "hite grain", ill get `wholegrain` and not `white bread`

I hope someone knows what the reason/fix is for this, thanks!

**php code:**
Here is how i would bind the params, execute the query, and retrieve the data:

```
$statement_handle = $db_handle->prepare($breadSQL);
foreach($searchWord as $i=>$q) {
    $q = "%".$q."%";
    $statement_handle->bindParam(":q$i", $q);
}
$statement_handle->execute(); 
$statement_handle->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
while($row = $statement_handle->fetch())
{
    $breadList[] = array('breadName' => $row['bread_name']);
}
```

**The fixed code:**

```
foreach($searchWord as $i=>$q) {
    $q = "%".$q."%";
    $statement_handle->bindValue(":q$i", $q, PDO::PARAM_STR);
}
```

Comment: Missing an `AND`, or is that a bad copy/paste?

Comment: Sorry, really bad copy and paste. 3am where i am :) I'll double check it.

Comment: I think you need to post the rest of your code.  If you're always returning the last record, sounds like something else might be wrong.

Comment: I've added the code portion for executing the query and retrieving the data

Comment: Use `bindValue` instead of `bindParam`. `bindParam` takes a *reference to the value*, not the value itself, and reads its value when it needs to build the whole query. The way you build this query means it will capture multiple references to the same `$q` variable, and reading their values will of course produce identical values.

Comment: possible duplicate of [All columns being set to the same value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10633229/all-columns-being-set-to-the-same-value)

Comment: Thank you, that solved it! Wow..... Can i accept your comment as an answer?

Answer (score 0):

try use those params with quotes

```
:q0 = '%hite%'
:q1 = '%grain%'
:q2 = '%brown%'
```